# AWS SDK Error: Failed to get the Amazon S3 bucket name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am attempting to setup AWS with an Elastic Beanstalk instance I have previously created. I have entered the various details into the config file, however when I try to use `aws.push` I get the error message

`Updating the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment x-xxxxxx...
Error: Failed to get the Amazon S3 bucket name`

I have checked the credentials in IAM and have full administrator privileges. When I run `eb status show green` I get the following message:

`InvalidClientTokenId. The security token included in the request is invalid.`

Comment: I know this is 11 months old. Have you figured it out? Are your AWS credentials correct?

Answer (score 0):

Run `aws configure` again, and re-enter your credentials.

It's likely you're using old (disabled or deleted) access/secret keys, or you accidentally swapped the access key with the secret key.

Answer (score 0):

For me is was that my system clock was off by more than 5 minutes. Updating the time fixed the issue.